# program in java to get info about Ram

Tags: java, ram

I want a program to get information about RAM

How can i do that?

Comment: Did you want to download and run this program, or did you want to write and program it yourself?

Comment: My suggestion would be to first *attempt* a solution and then ask the question. It is does not look good if you are just being lazy and do not want to put in any effort.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of memory-related methods in the [`Runtime`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class, but note that they only give information about the amount of memory available to (or used by) the JVM, not the hardware it runs on.

Generally, Java is the wrong language to do this kind of thing, since it requires access to OS APIs that Java does not provide.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the information you need will be contained in the [Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class. Have a look at the link. It should be straightforward. If you run into problems with it, I will try to help you out further.